# ¿Cómo evitar que se sobrepongan fragments en Java Android?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, recyclerview

**Hola, compañeros**. Se ha escrito mucho sobre este problema, pero las respuestas que he encontrado en la red datan de mucho atrás (años), y no me funcionan.

**Mi problema:** Cuando muestro un nuevo fragment, el fragment anterior no se reemplaza, es decir, se queda ahí como un horrible background, y encima se pone el nuevo fragment, parecido a como se ve en esta imagen:

[image: Superposición de fragments].

Lo único que sí funciona es la simple recomendación de cambiar el color de background del nuevo fragment, con lo cual logramos que no se vea lo que está detrás. Supongo que ésta es la solución menos elegante que puede darse, ya que en realidad eso no soluciona el problema de fondo, pues el fragment anterior sigue estando ahí, sólo que no se ve.

**Preguntas:**

1. ¿Tengo que conformarme con cambiar el background del nuevo fragment,
   pues en realidad no pasa nada con el hecho de que el fragment
   anterior esté ahí debajo?
2. ¿Existe alguna otra solución además de
   cambiar el background el nuevo fragment?

Pongo aquí el código resumido de la clase donde se encuentra el reemplazo de fragment que estoy intentando hacer:

```
public class MiClase extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MiClase.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;

    List<Elemento> elementos;

    public MiClase(List<Elemento> elementos, Context context) {
        super();
        this.elementos = elementos;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.elementos_list, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final Elemento elemento = elementos.get(position);

        holder.textViewAtributo1.setText(elemento.getAtributo1());
        holder.textViewAtributo2.setText(elemento.getAtributo2());

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentManager fm = ((AppCompatActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentNuevo fragmentNuevo = new FragmentNuevo();
                fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedorFragments, fragmentNuevo).addToBackStack(null).commit();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**EDICION 1 (20-may-2020)**

Mi proyecto está basado en una de las plantillas que trae por defecto Android Studio, llamada *Navigation Drawer*, y en su estructura, los fragments se cargan en: *content_main.xml*, que contiene esto:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:id="@+id/contenedorFragments">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Como verán, al layout como tal le puse el id *contenedorFragments*. Por tanto, el activity_main.xml no contiene como tal el contenedorFragments.

Comment: el contenedorFragments esta ubicado en la actividad principal?, es decit contenedorFragments es el id de un contenedor del xml de la actividad principal en la cual nacen los fragments?

Comment: Puedes usar .removeAllViews() en tu FrameLayout(contenedorFragments) antes de empezar la transicion.

Comment: @Sergio, edité la pregunta respondiendo tu pregunta. Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que tienes inicialmente en tu layout un `Fragment`, si deseas realizar un "reemplazo" de un `Fragment`, **solo puede reemplazar un Fragment agregado dinámicamente". Los Fragments definidos en un layout no pueden ser reemplazados.**

Por lo tanto en lugar de un `Fragment`:

```
  <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
    ...
    ...
   />
```

usa un `FrameLayout` en el cual no defines un Fragment, pero si puedes realizar reemplazos de Fragmentos dentro de este elemento:

```
  <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
    ...
    ...
   />
```